# Return string when inside a while loop

Tags: c#

I've tried google, and the advance search here. No luck.

```
Class SomeClass
{
    public string MethodName()
    {
    //Some Code
        While(conditions)
        {
            //More Code
            string X;
            X = "string stuff";
            return X;
        }
    }
}
```

I get a 'not all code paths return a value' error. I'm sure I can work around this but I'd like to know how to solve this for future reference.

Comment: What if your `conditions` is `false`? Your method will not return anything in this case but compiler can't know it's value.

Comment: you need to add a return at the end of your method. the `while` loop may return a string, but the method doesn't.

Comment: Please [search for messages](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BC%23%5D+not+all+code+paths+return+a+value) first; then read about the cause(s) of such an error, think about it a little bit, and then follow some of the suggestions to fix the code. If there is *still* a problem after that, then ask it: making sure to differentiate it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error because you are trying to return value from while loop which is not possible

Problem here if your while loop condition is not satisfied than no value get return that is the reason compiler giving you error.

Solution to this is , return empty string outside while loop that you function is returning value.

```
public string functionname
{
    while(conditions)
    {
      //More Code
      string X;
      X = "string stuff";
      return X;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Returning from a while loop is fine.

Comment: @StuartLC - its fine to return from while loop but if while loop condition not satisfy in that case we need to return some defualt value like empty string that my point...

Answer (score 2):

Think if `while` loop condition is not met, would your method return string? So put the return just before end of method to ensure that your method will always return string, this MSDN error page [not all code paths return a value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cz4k9t(v=vs.90).aspx) would further help you to understand.

I believe the sample code is just to show the problem as it does not make much sense to me.

```
public string MethodName() 
{
    //Some Code
    While(conditions) {
        //More Code
        string X;
        X = "string stuff";
        return X;
    }
    return "somestringifnotX";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler believes there is a path where conditions is NOT met on the first time it hits the while:

```
//Some Code
while(conditions)
{
  //More Code
  string X;
  X = "string stuff";
  return X;
}
.. Problem!
return "not found"; // or throw new Exception("I'm not supposed to be here")
```

What you need to do is also return (or throw!) in the instance where `conditions` aren't met at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < MethodName().Count; i++ )
        {
            var result = MethodName()[i] as string;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<string> MethodName()
    {
        var items = new List<string>();

        while (Condition)
        {
            items.Add("SString to return");
        }

        return items;
    }
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you will not return anything when you don't pass your while loop

```
Class SomeClass
{
  public string MethodName()
  {
    //Some Code
    While(conditions)
    {
      //More Code
      string X;
      X = "string stuff";
      return X;
    }
    return "Nothing to return Actually";
    //OR
    Throw new Exception("Conditions where false");
  }
}
```

Imagine you're conditions = false and you never entered the while. This means you will never get to the return. your function on the other hand needs one. End your statement with a return or throw an error when you don't want that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string binarySearch(int [] dataArray, int dataDicari) 
{
      int first = 0;
      int last = list.length – 1;
      int mid;       

      while (first <= last)
      {
          mid = (first+last)/2;
          if (dataArray[mid] == dataDicari)
              return ......;               //ISIAN 1                        
          else if (dataArray[mid] < dataDicari) 
              first = mid + 1;
          else if (dataArray[mid] > dataDicari) 
              last = mid – 1;
      }

      return .....;    //ISIAN 2
}
```